# share service data b/w two component in angular 2 using get set method

Tags: html, angular

**Here is my first component**
**requirement**:display data in second component which is sent by first component.

**current status**: i set data into service get set method and get also the data data but unable to display same data which is set by first component template .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from './myservicedata';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';// add file for navigate from one page to another page 

@Component({
  selector: 'tab-one',
  templateUrl: './tabone.component.html',
   providers:[ConfigService]  
})
export class taboneComponent {
  constructor(public configservice:ConfigService,private router:Router) {}
  formData(data:any){
    this.configservice.set_service_data(data);
    console.log("value of data which is set by me into service"+ data);
}

// for navigate from one url to another url
navigate(){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/tab_two');

}

}
```

**Here is my second component**

```
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
 import { ConfigService } from './myservicedata';
 import 'rxjs/Rx'; // add this file for use the map feature.
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-two',
  templateUrl: './tabtwo.component.html',
    // providers:[ConfigService]  
})

export class tabtwoComponent {
  public getterSetter:any=[];
  // public  store_service_data:any=[];
   constructor(private configservice:ConfigService) {}
      ngOnInit(){
        this.configservice.get_service_data()       
      }        

showdata(){
  console.log( this.configservice.get_service_data());

}

};
```

**Here is my service**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  private _url:string="../mockData.json";
 public serviceData:any=[];
 get_service_data():any{
    return  this.serviceData;
    //  this.serviceData.map(
    //    (response:Response) =>  response.json()
    //  );        
                       }; 

 set_service_data(value:any):void{
     this.serviceData=value;
                                 };

constructor(private http:Http) {}
  // Uses http.get() to load a single JSON file  
  getFriendsData():any {
    return this.http.get(this._url).map(
        (response:Response) =>  response.json()            
                                       );
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the providers array in your `TaboneComponent` and make sure `ConfigService` is in the providers array in your `app.module.ts`

**Explanation:**

In order to retrieve the information from the service what you want is to make sure that both your components reference the same instance on your `ConfigService`

Angular uses hierarchical dependency injection, which means whenever a dependency like your `ConfigService` is requested, Angular will traverse up the component tree to find a place where it has already been provided and pass that instance to the requester.

Because of this, you can easily create a singleton instance by providing a service in your app module as every component is a child of this.

When you provide the service like you have done in your `TaboneComponent` you are saying give me a new instance of this service even if one has already been provided somewhere else. Any component that is a child of tab-one will be able to get the data you have set in that service, but anything that is not a child will not.

You can read more about  Angular's dependency injection here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: i add in app.module.ts like this  providers:[ConfigService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] and remove providers[] from both component but still not working

Comment: Hey, ok. The next step is to now check the times at which you set the data in the service and request it, it's possible that you are asking for the data before it has been set. You have a console log after you set the data in `tabone`, add a console log in the `ngOnInit` of `tabtwo` and check which one gets logged first

Comment: yes man thanks for your support now its working fine thanks once again hates off...

Comment: Good stuff, no worries :)